# How to prevent browser from reloading timed out pages on resumed connection

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, internet-connection, opera

If I loose internet connection and open a page, or if I start the browser without having internet, the pages time out (don't load). If then my connection resumes, all those timed out / crashed pages soon automatically reload themselves all at once.

This is a privacy concern as well as a drain and sudden slowdown on my laptop.

How can I force my browser to never reload pages on its own? (any browser)

(PS: I know javascript can refresh (elements of) already-loaded pages, that's not what I'm asking about)

Answer (score 2):

#### Google Chrome

Navigate to:

> chrome://flags/

Find and set to *Disabled*:

> **Offline Auto-Reload Mode**
>
> Pages that fail to load while the browser is
> offline will be auto-reloaded when the browser is online again. – Mac,
> Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android
>
> #enable-offline-auto-reload

Comment: in chromium 117, this setting is no longer under `chrome://flags/`. instead, you can use the [command line switch](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) `chromium --disable-auto-reload`